# Angular ui-router - how to assign resolved data to state data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How do I assign resolved data into state data w/o going in the controller code?

following code fails

```
.state('restaurant', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/:restaurantId/:restaurantName',
    resolve: {
        restaurant: ['RestaurantFactory', '$stateParams', '$state', function (RestaurantFactory, $stateParams, $state) {
            return RestaurantFactory.query({ restaurantId: $stateParams.restaurantId });
        }]
    },
    data: {
        restaurant: resolve.restaurant // fails
    },
    views: {
        'content@': {
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/restaurant/restaurant.html',                        
            controllerAs: 'RestCtrl',
            controller: ['restaurant', 'RestaurantFactory', 'AppLib', 'Page', '$scope', '$state', function (restaurant, RestaurantFactory, AppLib, Page, $scope, $state) {
                var vm = this;
                // public properties
                vm.AppLib = AppLib;
                vm.Page = Page;
                vm.restaurant = restaurant;
                $state.restaurant = restaurant;

                $scope.$on('Restaurant_Changed', function (event, data) { if (data.id === vm.restaurant.id) { vm.restaurant = data; $state.restaurant = data; } });
            }]
        }
    }
})
```

The reason I need this functionality is that one of the child state overwrites the content@ view (kind of brings entire content of its own) and as a result parent's controller is never fired if I access child states page directly. Is there a way to accomplish this as I want to use parent state URL and ability to share data down to children/grandchildren states

Any ideas?

---

**Solution**

Big thanks to Yang Li for giving me this suggestion. Here is how I solved it

```
resolve: {
    restaurant: ['RestaurantFactory', '$stateParams', '$state', '$q', function (RestaurantFactory, $stateParams, $state, $q) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        RestaurantFactory.query({ restaurantId: $stateParams.restaurantId })
        .then(function (data) {
            $state.restaurant = data;                            
            deferred.resolve($state.restaurant);
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            deferred.reject(data);
        })

        return deferred.promise;
    }],                    
},
```

Comment: restaurant: ['RestaurantFactory', '$stateParams', '$state', function (RestaurantFactory, $stateParams, $state) {
            return RestaurantFactory.query({ restaurantId: $stateParams.restaurantId });
        }] <---- put this in data?

Comment: Nope, code was not executed when I put it in data. Thanks though!

Comment: In your resolve try: $state.restaurant.data.restaurant = RestaurantFactory.query({ restaurantId: $stateParams.restaurantId });

Comment: Thanks, it worked with help of deferred resolve.